# Django: Setting up multiple databases using sqlite3

Tags: django, django-models

I have been trying to setup my project on Django1.3 to use multiple databases, in my case different sqlite3 files. I have been reading the Django documentation as well a lot of googling but in vain.

**Problems faced**

1. When using the syncdb with --database, why the tables for that particular application are not getting created in either default database or the other db?
2. Django framework internal tables like auth are getting created for all the databases mentioned. Is this the way the feature is supposed to behave OR I have wrongly configured the same?

**My Code**

***settings.py***

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "db/defaultdb.sqlite"),
    },
    'app1': {
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'NAME': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "db/app1db.sqlite"),
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['dbrouter.MyAppRouter']
```

**dbrouter.py**

```
class MyAppRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app1':
            return 'app1db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app1':
            return 'app1db'
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'app1db':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'app1'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'app1':
            return False
        return None
```

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `db_for_read` and `db_for_write` methods,

```
if model._meta.app_label == 'app1':
    return 'app1db'
return None
```

You must return the db alias, which is `app1` according to your `settings.DATABASES`. There is a similar issue in your `allow_syncdb` method.  Have you read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/)?